# Spring MVC Exception Handling with @controlleradvice

Tags: spring-mvc, exception

I am making a project in Spring MVC in which I need to use global exception handling for which I am using @controlleradvice and @exceptionhandler. The problem is every time I am throwing an exception it is showing the normal Tomcat exception rather than showing my customized error page.

The code for my global controller is as follows:

```
package com.mphasis.insurance.controller;

import java.sql.*;
import org.springframework.http.HttpStatus;
import org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ControllerAdvice;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.method.annotation.ResponseEntityExceptionHandler;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;

@ControllerAdvice
@EnableWebMvc
public class GlobalExceptionHandler extends ResponseEntityExceptionHandler 
{

    @ExceptionHandler(value=RuntimeException.class)
    public ModelAndView handle(RuntimeException ex)
    {

        System.out.println("Runtime Exception Occured");
        return new ModelAndView("RuntimeException");
    }
    @ExceptionHandler(value=NullPointerException.class)
    public ModelAndView handleNullPointerException(NullPointerException ex)
    {

        System.out.println("Null Pointer Exception Occured");
        return new ModelAndView("NullPointerException");
    }
    @ExceptionHandler(value=ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException.class)
    public ModelAndView handleArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException ex)
    {

        System.out.println("Array Index Out Of BoundsException Occured");
        return new ModelAndView("ArrayIndexOutOfoundException");
    }
    @ExceptionHandler(value=ArithmeticException.class)
    public ModelAndView handleArithmeticException(ArithmeticException ex)
    {

        System.out.println("Arithmetic Exception Occured");
        return new ModelAndView("ArithmeticException");
    }
    @ExceptionHandler(value=SQLException.class)
    public ModelAndView handleSQLException(SQLException ex)
    {
        System.out.println("SQL Exception Occured");
        return new ModelAndView("SQLException");
    }
    @ExceptionHandler(value=NumberFormatException.class)
    public ModelAndView handleNumberFormatException(NumberFormatException ex)
    {
        System.out.println("Number Format Exception Occured");
        return new ModelAndView("NumberFormatException");
    }
}
```

Comment: Is this class definitely getting initialised? Try add a @PostConstruct method to make sure it is.

Comment: Also you don't need the @ EnableWebMvc annotation on a @ ControllerAdvice class. That should only be in one place: on your relevant @ Configuration class.

Comment: thanks for the advice.I am new to spring framework so can you please show how can i add @PostConstruct to my method.

Comment: yes i did use @PostConstruct but its still not working.

Comment: Sorry I mean you should use @PostConstruct to make sure this class is actually initialised by Spring. Make a method that just does a System.out.println with some message and make sure you can see that message in your console when you start your application.

Comment: As suggested by @Plog remove the EnableWebMvc from this class

Comment: I did all that you suggested but there is nothing printed on the console.

Comment: That probably means that Spring isn't picking up this class. Can you post your @Configuration class that includes your component scan?

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Spring is a complex framework, and configuring it correctly is not always easy. Can you look in the server logs to see whether Spring was correctly initialized, and also spring-mvc, and is that `GlobalExceptionHandler` correctly initialized as a bean?